# Sencha Touch cmd - what do different sencha.cfg files do?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd, sencha-touch-2.3

In the Sencha Touch docs, the command utility help pages has the following info below:

```
.sencha/                # Sencha-specific files (for example configuration)
    app/                # Application-specific content
        sencha.cfg      # Configuration file for Sencha Cmd
        plugin.xml      # Plugin for Sencha Cmd
    workspace/          # Workspace-specific content (see below)
        sencha.cfg      # Configuration file for Sencha Cmd
        plugin.xml      # Plugin for Sencha Cmd

touch/                  # A copy of the Sencha Touch SDK
    cmd/                # Sencha Touch-specific content for Sencha Cmd
        sencha.cfg      # Configuration file for Sencha Cmd
        plugin.xml      # Plugin for Sencha Cmd
    src/                # The Sench Touch source
    sencha-touch-*.js   # Pre-compiled and bootstrap files
    ...
```

What I don't understand is why the SAME file is duplicated throughout the tree structure but effectively is explained as the same thing; 'Configuration file for Sencha Cmd'.

Ok....so what does each actually do?  I'd like to be able to build my app for production into a different folder on my build server than on my own dev machine. Does this mean that I can have different settings in the /app folder compared to the /workspace folder? How do I ensure the build server picks up settings from the /app folder and not the /workspace folder then?

Little confused.

Answer (score 1):

This file is the file in charge of the configuring the build process of various ExtJS/Sencha touch applications and packages (Which are pieces of software that can be reused). 
The precedence of these files is:

1. Settings from command line arguments as in: sencha ant -Dfoo=bar
2. app level sencha.cfg
3. worspace level sencha app
4. SDK level sencha app

The properties defined in these files can tweak things like what actual SDK you're using, if you're doing production or testing build, how would you compress the output,  what parts of the build you choose to omit (e.g: Don't compile the theme) and more.